# Handling Empty List in ExpandableListView in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am trying to create multiple categories in an activity which extends ExpandableListActivity. Now some of the categories have items and some dont. but when I click on the EmptyList ones I get a Force Close message with null pointers.

I am trying to hide the Arrow Indicator when the list is empty or just not do anything since it doesnt have items.

Can someone please help me with an example if possible.

Regards

Comment: Could you post some code along with the error you're getting (maybe the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

We can't have a group with no child in other words group should have the instance of the `ExpandListChild`,
So just follow these steps

```
ArrayList<ExpandListChild> list2 = new ArrayList<ExpandListChild>();
ExpandListGroup gru5 = new ExpandListGroup();
    gru5.setName("Home");
    gru5.setItems(list2);
```

There is no need to add any item in the `ExpandListChild`

Hope this will help you